# How to create a custom "update" function in Godot using GDscript?

Tags: coroutine, godot, gdscript

I want something somewhat equivalent to this code that was written in C# for Unity. I want to be able to call an "diy_update()" function whenever I want and end that process according to a Boolean.

```
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(DIY_Update());
    }

    IEnumerator DIY_Update()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if(randomBoolean)
            {
                break;
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }
```

This obviously make the code stop and await until `DIY_Update()` finishes, therefor is not what I wanted.

```
extends Node

func _ready():
    await(DIY_Update())

func DIY_Update():
    while true:
        if random_boolean():
            break
        await(null)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Unity doing `yield return null;` will have the execution of the coroutine resumes in the following frame.

We can do that in Godot by awaiting the [`process_frame`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_scenetree.html#class-scenetree-signal-process-frame) signal:

```
await get_tree().process_frame
```

---

*I also want to point out that you can control if Godot calls `_process` by calling [`set_process`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node.html#class-node-method-set-process).*